# How to create function that can be used with switch button in Tkniter GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to build a GUI with Tkinter and use it to control my Raspberry Pi robot.
With some help, I managed to get the functionality of the buttons when being pressed and held down but I am struggling with the function that
will allow me to do things with the switch button.
[image]

here is a quick snippet of the Tkinter code:

```
# LED  Lights
self.led_switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=self.lights_control, text="LED", 
command=lambda: self.led_switch())
self.led_switch.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="n")
```

and here is the function I'm trying to implement:

```
is_on = True
def led_switch(self, event):
    global is_on

    if is_on:
        print("It is on")
        #is_on = False
    else:
        print("It is off")

        #is_on = True
```

This doesn't seem to work since I'm getting the error message:

```
 self.led_switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=self.lights_control, text="LED", command=lambda: self.led_switch())
```

TypeError: 'CTkSwitch' object is not callable`.

here is the full code if that helps:

```
   import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import customtkinter

# Setting up theme
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # configure window
        self.title("Cool Blue")
        self.geometry(f"{1200}x{560}")

        # configure grid layout (4x4)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2, 3, 4), weight=1)
        self.bind("<KeyPress>", self.key_pressed)
        self.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.key_released)


        ###################################################################
        # create sidebar frame for controls
        ###################################################################
        self.sidebar_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=100)
        self.sidebar_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 10), sticky="nsew")
        self.sidebar_frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

        # Setting up grid label
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="Motion",  font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=15, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        # Setting up W - Forward button
        self.button_up = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, text="W", height=10, width=10)
        self.button_up.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=10)
        self.button_up.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda x: self.motion_event_start(x, 'W'))
        self.button_up.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda x: self.motion_event_stop(x, 'W'))

        # Setting up S - Backwards buttons
        self.button_down = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, text="S", height=10, width=10)
        self.button_down.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=20, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=10)
        self.button_down.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda x: self.motion_event_start(x, 'S'))
        self.button_down.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda x: self.motion_event_stop(x, 'S'))

        # Setting up A - Left button
        self.button_left = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, text="A", height=10, width=10)
        self.button_left.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=10)
        self.button_left.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda x: self.motion_event_start(x, 'A'))
        self.button_left.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda x: self.motion_event_stop(x, 'A'))

        # Setting up D - Right button
        self.button_right = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, text="D", height=10, width=10)
        self.button_right.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=10)
        self.button_right.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda x: self.motion_event_start(x, 'D'))
        self.button_right.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda x: self.motion_event_stop(x,'D'))


        ###################################################################
        # Create Sidebar for arm control
        ###################################################################
        self.arm_control = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.arm_control.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan = 1, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 10), sticky="nsew")
        self.arm_control.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

        # Setting up grid label
        self.arm_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.arm_control, text="Arm",  font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=15, weight="bold"))
        self.arm_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))
        self.grip_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.arm_control, text="Grip",  font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=15, weight="bold"))
        self.grip_label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        # Arm Up
        self.button_arm_up = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.arm_control, text="    Up   ", height=10, width=10)
        self.button_arm_up.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=30, ipady=10)
        # Arm Down
        self.button_arm_down = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.arm_control, text=" Down", height=10, width=10)
        self.button_arm_down.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=30, ipady=10)

        self.button_grip_open = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.arm_control, text="Open", height=10, width=10)
        self.button_grip_open.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=30, ipady=10, sticky="w")

        self.button_grip_close = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.arm_control, text="Close", height=10, width=10)
        self.button_grip_close.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=30, ipady=10, sticky="w")


        ###################################################################
        # Create Sidebar for grip
        ###################################################################
        self.lights_control = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.lights_control.grid(row=3, column=0, rowspan = 1, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 10), sticky="nsew")
        self.lights_control.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        # LED  Lights
        self.led_switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=self.lights_control, text="LED", command=lambda: self.led_switch)
        self.led_switch.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="n")

        # Regular Lights
        self.regular_ligths_switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=self.lights_control, text="Lights", command=lambda: print("switch 1 toggle"))
        self.regular_ligths_switch.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=20)

        # Camera
        self.led_switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=self.lights_control, text="Camera", command=lambda: print("switch 1 toggle"))
        self.led_switch.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, )

        # create Video Canvas
        self.picam = customtkinter.CTkCanvas(self, width=800, background="gray")
        self.picam.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=4, padx=(5, 5), pady=(20, 20), sticky="nsew")
        self.picam.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

        self.picam_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.picam, text="Live Stream", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.picam_label.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="")

        # create radiobutton frame
        self.temperature = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.temperature.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan = 1, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 10), sticky="n")
        self.temperature.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.label_temperature = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.temperature, text="Temperature")
        self.label_temperature.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="")

        # create checkbox and switch frame
        self.pressure = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.pressure.grid(row=1, column=3, rowspan = 1, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 10), sticky="n")
        self.pressure.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.label_pressure = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.pressure, text="Pressure")
        self.label_pressure.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="")

        # create checkbox and switch frame
        self.humidity = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.humidity.grid(row=3, column=3, rowspan = 1, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 10), sticky="")
        self.humidity.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.label_humidity = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.humidity, text="Humidity")
        self.label_humidity.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="")


    def key_pressed(self, event):
        if event.char in 'wads':
            self.motion_event_start(event, event.char.upper())

    def key_released(self, event):
        if event.char in 'wads':
            self.motion_event_stop(event, event.char.upper())

    def motion_event_start(self, event, button):
        # if button == "W":
        #     kit1.motor1.throttle = 1
        #     kit2.motor1.throttle = 1
        # elif button == "S":
        #     kit1.motor1.throttle = -1
        #     kit2.motor1.throttle = -1

        print(f"{button} Pressed")

    def motion_event_stop(self, event, button):
        print(f"{button} Released")
        # kit1.motor1.throttle = 0
        # kit2.motor1.throttle = 0

    
    # Switch
    
    is_on = True
    def led_switch(self, event):
        global is_on

        if is_on:
            print("It is on")
            #is_on = False
        else:
            print("It is off")

            #is_on = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Unrealted but you should changed `command=lambda: self.led_switch()` to `command=self.led_switch`. There is no reason to use lambda here unless you need to pass something to the function.

Comment: We will need a little more to test the issue. From what I can tell you are missing the variable requirement and the on off values.

Comment: @Mike - i tried using just led_switch but nothing happens. 
I am going to post the entire code so you can see it.

Comment: From my testing with just a minimum setup your CKTSwitch should work fine. Normally when your get the error about not being able to load an object it lies elsewhere. For example you have not set up your mainloop properly or an issue with imports.

Comment: @Mike-SMT - I just posted the full code. The part I'm looking is under # Led section. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 problems with your overall logic.

This line:

```
self.led_switch=customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=self.lights_control, text="LED", command=lambda: self.led_switch)
```

Should be:

```
self.led_switch=customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=self.lights_control, text="LED", command=self.led_switch)
```

This is because lambda is not needed here and your lambda: call was only saving a reference to the function and not actually calling it when triggered.

Next you need to change the function that is receiving the call since you are not explicitly passing an event and it is expecting on.

So change this:

```
def led_switch(self, event):
    global is_on

    if is_on:
        print("It is on")
        is_on = False
    else:
        print("It is off")
        is_on = True
```

To this:

```
# You can use event=None or remove event or use another option if needed.
def led_switch(self, event=None):
    global is_on

    if is_on:
        print("It is on")
        is_on = False
    else:
        print("It is off")
        is_on = True
```

Lastly you do not actually have `is_on = True` in the global namespace so it cannot be referenced where you have it.

Either add it to your class init as a class attribute or move it out of the class to the global namespace.

Personally I would go with the class attribute route to avoid using global.
The below version uses a class attribute instead of global.

Here is a corrected version of your code.

```
import customtkinter

# Setting up theme
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # configure window
        self.is_on = True
        self.title("Cool Blue")
        self.geometry(f"{1200}x{560}")

        # configure grid layout (4x4)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2, 3, 4), weight=1)
        self.bind("<KeyPress>", self.key_pressed)
        self.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.key_released)

        ###################################################################
        # create sidebar frame for controls
        ###################################################################
        self.sidebar_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=100)
        self.sidebar_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 10), sticky="nsew")
        self.sidebar_frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

        # Setting up grid label
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="Motion",
                                                 font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=15, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        # Setting up W - Forward button
        self.button_up = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, text="W", height=10, width=10)
        self.button_up.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=10)
        self.button_up.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda x: self.motion_event_start(x, 'W'))
        self.button_up.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda x: self.motion_event_stop(x, 'W'))

        # Setting up S - Backwards buttons
        self.button_down = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, text="S", height=10, width=10)
        self.button_down.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=20, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=10)
        self.button_down.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda x: self.motion_event_start(x, 'S'))
        self.button_down.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda x: self.motion_event_stop(x, 'S'))

        # Setting up A - Left button
        self.button_left = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, text="A", height=10, width=10)
        self.button_left.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=10)
        self.button_left.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda x: self.motion_event_start(x, 'A'))
        self.button_left.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda x: self.motion_event_stop(x, 'A'))

        # Setting up D - Right button
        self.button_right = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, text="D", height=10, width=10)
        self.button_right.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=10, ipady=10)
        self.button_right.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda x: self.motion_event_start(x, 'D'))
        self.button_right.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda x: self.motion_event_stop(x, 'D'))

        ###################################################################
        # Create Sidebar for arm control
        ###################################################################
        self.arm_control = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.arm_control.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=1, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 10), sticky="nsew")
        self.arm_control.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

        # Setting up grid label
        self.arm_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.arm_control, text="Arm",
                                                font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=15, weight="bold"))
        self.arm_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))
        self.grip_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.arm_control, text="Grip",
                                                 font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=15, weight="bold"))
        self.grip_label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        # Arm Up
        self.button_arm_up = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.arm_control, text="    Up   ", height=10, width=10)
        self.button_arm_up.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=30, ipady=10)
        # Arm Down
        self.button_arm_down = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.arm_control, text=" Down", height=10, width=10)
        self.button_arm_down.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=30, ipady=10)

        self.button_grip_open = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.arm_control, text="Open", height=10, width=10)
        self.button_grip_open.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=30, ipady=10, sticky="w")

        self.button_grip_close = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.arm_control, text="Close", height=10, width=10)
        self.button_grip_close.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=30, ipady=10, sticky="w")

        ###################################################################
        # Create Sidebar for grip
        ###################################################################
        self.lights_control = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.lights_control.grid(row=3, column=0, rowspan=1, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 10), sticky="nsew")
        self.lights_control.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        # LED  Lights
        self.led_switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=self.lights_control, text="LED",
                                                  command= self.led_switch)
        self.led_switch.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="n")

        # Regular Lights
        self.regular_ligths_switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=self.lights_control, text="Lights",
                                                             command=lambda: print("switch 1 toggle"))
        self.regular_ligths_switch.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=20)

        # Camera
        self.led_switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=self.lights_control, text="Camera",
                                                  command=lambda: print("switch 1 toggle"))
        self.led_switch.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, )

        # create Video Canvas
        self.picam = customtkinter.CTkCanvas(self, width=800, background="gray")
        self.picam.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=4, padx=(5, 5), pady=(20, 20), sticky="nsew")
        self.picam.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

        self.picam_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.picam, text="Live Stream",
                                                  font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.picam_label.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="")

        # create radiobutton frame
        self.temperature = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.temperature.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan=1, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 10), sticky="n")
        self.temperature.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.label_temperature = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.temperature, text="Temperature")
        self.label_temperature.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="")

        # create checkbox and switch frame
        self.pressure = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.pressure.grid(row=1, column=3, rowspan=1, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 10), sticky="n")
        self.pressure.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.label_pressure = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.pressure, text="Pressure")
        self.label_pressure.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="")

        # create checkbox and switch frame
        self.humidity = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.humidity.grid(row=3, column=3, rowspan=1, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 10), sticky="")
        self.humidity.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.label_humidity = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.humidity, text="Humidity")
        self.label_humidity.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="")

    def key_pressed(self, event):
        if event.char in 'wads':
            self.motion_event_start(event, event.char.upper())

    def key_released(self, event):
        if event.char in 'wads':
            self.motion_event_stop(event, event.char.upper())

    def motion_event_start(self, event, button):
        # if button == "W":
        #     kit1.motor1.throttle = 1
        #     kit2.motor1.throttle = 1
        # elif button == "S":
        #     kit1.motor1.throttle = -1
        #     kit2.motor1.throttle = -1

        print(f"{button} Pressed")

    def motion_event_stop(self, event, button):
        print(f"{button} Released")
        # kit1.motor1.throttle = 0
        # kit2.motor1.throttle = 0

    # Switch

    def led_switch(self, event=None):
        if self.is_on:
            print("It is on")
            self.is_on = False
        else:
            print("It is off")
            self.is_on = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

From my testing this fixes your issue:

[image]

[image]